# Is this close enough for ignition timing setting?

Tags: ignition, timing-set

Having a hard time aligning the bottom pointer with the V above it while setting the ignition timing.

They’re supposed to line up with the middle line of the three |||

Is this close enough or should I keep trying?[image][image]

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Comment: 98 Honda Civic D16Y8 engine

Comment: From the drawing, it looks like the three lines are at 10, 12 and 14 degrees. So if you are outside the range of the lines, yes you should keep trying!  The "trick" is to spend some time *before* you start the engine, and  adjust the distributor clamping bolts so it will turn smoothly but not slip out of position while you stop moving it.

Comment: Why are you having a hard time?  Can you get the timing mark to move?

Comment: @HandyHowie Am I supposed to line up both pointers or can use either one? Trying to line up the bottom in between the top V is making it difficult

Comment: It looks like it is the the middle of the V that needs aligning.  You didn’t say why you are having difficulty.  Put a drop of white paint in the base of the v. It may help visibility, if that is the issue.

Comment: Put a white paint mark on the other edge of the pulley too, that may help.

Comment: @HandyHowie The issue is I’m a little confused. The diagram shows two pointers on the timing belt cover. Do I need to visibly align the two pointers like a gun sight to line up the mark on the pulley, or can I just use the V pointer?

Comment: @alephzero So as long as I’m in between the three lines it should be good? Or do I need to get it perfectly at the middle mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, I can now see what you are asking.

It looks like there is a pointer lower down in the shadow of your photo.  As you described in the comments you should use the V and the pointer like a gun sight.  This is to ensure you are looking from the correct angle.  You should be able to get all 3 markers in alignment.

If it makes things easier to see, add a white paint spot on the lower pointer and on the pulley.

You need to get them perfectly aligned, not just somewhere near.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn’t find anywhere anyone mentioning aligning both pointers like a gun sight. Makes it little trickier to align to the crankshaft mark. The diagram says needs to be at 12 degrees +/- 2. Does that mean you can get it close to the middle mark (12 degrees) and still be within spec and not notice a difference in how the car runs?

Comment: Yes, as close as possible, to 12, but no less than 10 and no greater than 14.  I have no guide as to what the pulley marks mean on your car engine, do you know what they mean?  It shouldn’t be difficult to get it spot on 12.

Comment: I believe the left mark is advanced and right one retarded. When I try to set it directly in the middle the car runs a little weak on power. If I set closer to the left mark it runs better

Comment: Maybe I should have been a bit clearer in what I said.  I understand one will be advanced and the other retarded, but by how much, 1 degree, 2 degrees, 4 degrees each mark?

Comment: Advancing the timing will likely improve power, but it can also cause damage to the engine if too far out.

Comment: I believe each right and left mark is a 2 degree difference from the middle one. Right now it’s more on the left mark so maybe 1 or 2 degrees advanced from the middle line. I’ll probably just keep it here

Comment: Emissions may also be affected by the timing being not set correctly.

Comment: May be a silly question but, do you close one eye to line up the two markers to get a line of sight or does that skew it?

Comment: It usually helps to look through one eye.